# Recognise biblatex option with custom style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am writing a custom citation style with my own `bbx` and `cbx` files. For certain things that I have to establish, `biblatex` already has package options (e.g. suppressing ISBN or using initials of authors). Can my custom style somehow impose the use of these options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely possible (and probably sensible) to recognise the standard options. Assuming your custom style is constructed using a standard one

```
\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}% Or numeric or authoryear or ...
```

then toggles such as `bbx:isbn` will be defined and can be used in for example

```
\iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
  {\printfield{isbn}}
  {}%
```

The can also be set as options

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{isbn = false}
```

so your custom style can do things 'it's own way'.

If you are working entirely from scratch then you'll need to define the standard options yourself

```
\newtoggle{bbx:isbn}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{isbn}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:isbn}{#1}%
}
```

but that is no different from declaring your own custom options

```
\newtoggle{bbx:myclever}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{mycleveroption}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:myclever}{#1}%
}
```